# "cd" in linux shell script returns "command not found!"

Tags: linux, shell

I have written a shell script called "a.sh" in linux with one line:

cd ..

: and then I run this with:

```
chmod +x a.sh
sh ./a.sh
```

: how do I run this without getting :

"Command not found" or "Can't cd". Maybe I have been looking at this code too long or am I doing something obviously wrong??

Note: I have since found out what was wrong. Emacs was inserting some strange "^m" character at the end of every line

Comment: `chmod +x a.sh sh ./a.sh` is not a valid command. Did you mean to show multiple lines? Also, can you paste the actual output from the command?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant them to be on multiple lines. I have amended the question now

Comment: With regard to your note: ^M is ASCII-13, the carriage return (CR); *nix clients only use the line feed (LF, ASCII-10) character on its own.  But Windows/DOS machines like to have both CRLF, resulting in ^M at the end of lines in situations where the difference is not being handled.  Did you write your script in windows and then run it on linux without conversion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

cd is a builtin to your shell. Anything like /usr/bin/cd or /bin/cd just there for weird magical reasons.

First run this.

```
which sh
```

This will output the path to your sh executable

Try adding a shebang to your script. So the entire file looks like this

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ..
```

If that doesn't work then clarify the steps you've taken as Stefan has asked. As well as paste the exact error message.

Answer (score -1):

what if you put /bin/cd in it's place.

Comment: Then I get:/bin/cd: No such file or directory

Comment: `cd` is a shell builtin. In fact it cannot be implemented as an external command, as changing the current directory within a child process wouldn't affect parent at all, and after child exits, nothing will be changed. See `chdir(2)`.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more. I don't understand what you are saying about external commands

Comment: External commands are programs that reside on the hard disk.  When you type their name in a shell, the shell loads that program, temporarily gives control to that program, and then resumes once that program finishes.  The shell that gives you the command prompt is itself a program, and it has several commands built in which are appropriately called builtins.  When you type the name of a builtin, the shell itself handles it, without loading and running another program.